# Excel: Highlight cells is all tests are duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using conditional formating I would like to look for duplicates in columns A, D, E. I would like I to highlight the row if a duplicate is found in column A and D and E. So I tried a formula =($A:$A)and($D:$D)and($E:$E) and also =if($A:$A)and($D:$D)and($E:$E) but neither seemed to work. I am not trying to find duplicates across the columns. Any help is appreciated. |a|b|c|d|e| **|1|3|4|2|x|** |2|3|4|2|x| **|1|5|4|2|x|**

Answer (score 1):

Use *Conditional Formatting* on Home ribbon.

1. Select the range of data, in my example, A1:E6
2. Under "Home" tab -> "Conditional Formatting"
3. "New Rule" -> "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."
4. Enter formula: `=AND(COUNTIF($A:$A, $A1)>1, COUNTIF($D:$D, $D1)>1, COUNTIF($E:$E, $E1)>1)`

See output below,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am looking for it to highlight the rows only if A, D, E all match. So in your example A would need to be 1 or 2 and D would need to be 1 or 2, and E matches with Z

Comment: Here is an example or what I desire the output to be
|A|B|C|D|E|
**|1|A|X|1|Z|**
|2|B|Y|2|A|
|1|C|Z|1|X|
|3|D|X|2|Z|
|2|E|Z|3|Y|
**|1|A|X|1|Z|**